# Spring Security LDAP user data caching on local database

Tags: authentication, caching, ldap, spring-security

After asking:
[LDAP user data caching on local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009740/ldap-user-data-caching-on-local-database)

I want to cache LDAP user data in the application local database to allow fast queries.

How may I cache LDAP user data in the local database using Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

build a local LDAP database and enable Replication (create a slave)